# Joining a path and an object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, path

I'm trying to make a pin icon, like a map pin.

I have a V shape as a path at the bottom, and a circle object above it, that has been trimmed.

How can I join these two together? If I use the unite tool it just deletes the V path.

[image]

The image above shows the paths - I have moved the circle bit up a touch for clarity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two closed shapes; using the *polygon* and *circle* tools instead of a path and shape. Combine the shapes using the *unite* option in the *Pathfinder* palette.

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. I copyedited your answer for legibility--if I changed anything beyond your intention, feel free to [edit] it again! If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Simon - but I get weird ends now, like this: http://i.imgur.com/ghjpr9d.png Any idea how to stop this happening?

Comment: @SimonCurry Don't worry, figured it out. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

**Forget** about Pathfinder or joining or any of that.... it seems you may be over-thinking this.

It's vector, right? All you need is one more anchor on the circle path, that's it.

Use the **Pen Tool** to **add an anchor** on the bottom circle path. Then use the **Direct Selection Tool** to click and drag that anchor downward creating the arrow.

Then delete that angle path, it's not needed.

[image]